# Clients connecting automatically to server with sockets java

Tags: java, sockets

Is there any way,java code, to make clients automatically establish connection to server with sockets in java.
I have some machines on a LAN network, one of them contains a server that listens to all connected clients,i want client to be able to listen server and connect immediately as soon as the server starts.

Comment: Hit the server on a loop? Make the clients listen on a different port to get notified by the server when it's up?

Comment: could you please explain this more

Comment: Can you formulate a clear question.  What have you tried?  What do you think you don't know?

Comment: i want my java client to listen some how to the server and connects to it as soon as it starts.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have two choices:

1. Write a loop in your client. Something like

   ```
   boolean connected = false;
   while (!connected) {
       connected = ... // try to connect
       Thread.sleep(/* some time */);
   }
   ```
2. Make the clients listen on a port. When the server starts up, it fires a trivial message to that port. When the client gets that message, they know the server is up and they can connect to the server.

Comment: I tried this `while(!connected){
 try{
   socket = new Socket("192.168.1.64", 5555);

connected=true;

  } catch (IOException ex) {  
 
 }
 
}` each time the sserver starts my client connects infinitely

Comment: @user2250162 We would need to see more code, presumably in a new question.